# Flag as Spam declined, which looks clearly a spam to me

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569022/free-wordpress-plug-in-to-customize-woocommerce-product-graphically) as spam, but it was declined with message.

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

As per criteria of SO to be spam

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

The question clearly appeared to me as promoting a website.
What am I missing?
Does it appears a spam only to me?

Comment: It is actually not spam

Comment: Did you actually read the question? It is a resource request giving the URL as an example of what OP is looking for. Of course it's a crap question and should be closed and deleted, but it's not spam - or if it is, it's really non-obvious as it's delivered as part of an actual programming question, even though that question is bad and off-topic for SO.

Comment: @l4mpi I THINK that the user saw it as someone who uses a bad post to actually publicize their own website. I don't know to what extent that's true,   but I believe that's what HE felt was spam-y looking. I am however with you that it isn't, per our definitions, spam

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I declined the flag, because that post does not fit our definition of spam.

Please don't use the spam flag for each and every resource request question where the OP links to an example site. That user is looking for functionality they found on a random site on the web. Linking to that random site does not make the question spam.